# Show that $(F,G_1;H,B)$ is an harmonic range in the figure below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry

Pythagoras/quadratic equations are illegal (but power of points).

[image]

$\triangle ABC$ is equilateral, $ACED$ is a rectangle, $G$ is the center of $\triangle ABC$. It's not hard to see that $H$ is midpoint of $AC$ and $F$ is midpoint of $ED$.

I also know that $AG_1CB$ is harmonic and I thought (incorrectly) that because $FA=FC$ and $AG_1CB$ is harmonic, then $AC$ should be polar of $F$ but althought the later result is true, this logic is false. Is there a nice way to see that $AF$ is tangent to the circle without calculating stuff?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ the midpoints of $AH$ and $CH$? That is the only way the problem is correct

Comment: @alduan you need to prove that. I don't think the rectangle can be different and have $G_1 \in (ABC)$

Comment: Oh i get it now, thanks for the clarification

Comment: what exactly is the location of E or D? I think there is a missing piece of information to understand how to define X and Y

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo I presume they are the only ones who create the rectangle in which $DX$ and $EY$ meet at the circuncircle of $\triangle ABC$

Comment: @hellofriends That makes no sense. For each E, D, setting a G, the X and Y are defined

Comment: Please complete the missing data in the statement so that the exercise can be solved.

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo notice that $X$ and $Y$ are on the lines $BE$ and $BD$

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo I think the problem is well defined, I don't think you can choose a random point and get all the alignments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete quadrangle $DEXY$ has the property that one pair of opposite sides intersect at $B$, a second pair intersect at $G_1$, and the third pair meet $BG_1$ at $F, H$. [Therefore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_quadrangle#Projective_properties), $FG_1HB$ is a harmonic range—indeed, the existence of such a quadrangle is often taken as the definition of a harmonic range.

This immediately proves the statement in your question title, but of course it ignores most of your diagram—which doesn’t make it wrong, but does make me wonder whether you’re working with a different definition.

Comment: I'm not used with pure projective geometry. You mean we can interpret $XY$ and $ED$ as digonals of $EDYX$?

Comment: Let $\infty = ED \cap XY$, then $BG_1FH \frac{E}{\overline\wedge} XY\infty H \frac{D}{\overline\wedge} G_1BFH$. Very nice.